# Does DVD+R have an MBR? If it does, can a virus that overwrites the MBR overwrite the MBR on the DVD+R?

Tags: virus

Does DVD+R have an MBR? If it does, can a virus that overwrites the MBR overwrite the MBR on the DVD+R?

I'm about to run a virus in a virtual machine with the DVD mounted because the virus is on the DVD, and I don't know if it's a virus that overwrites the MBR, so I don't know if it will overwrite the MBR of the DVD. I would like to know if it can overwrite the MBR before I run the virus.

Comment: Not if the DVD is read only

Comment: Thanks. That's useful. Can it overwrite if it's read and write?

Comment: No if the DVD was finalized, I think not also if the DVD is a multisession that is not closed. But anyway you can make sure the DVD+R was mounted read only.

Comment: if you're not booting from the DVD, does it even matter?